# Bayesian estimation of a mean with tighter constraints than the observations

Tags: bayesian, mean

The basic problem I have is very similar to a classic Bayesian estimation problem: there is a real valued parameters $p\in[0,1]$, that I would like to estimate via observations $o_i$.

It is also the case that
$$
p=\lim_{N\to\infty}{1\over N}\sum_{i=1}^N o_i,
$$
so this problem is very closely analogous to estimating a probability.

Here is the catch: $o_i\in[-1,1]$

Due to the similarity with estimating a probability, I would like to do something like a Bayesian update about my knowledge of $p$, where the prior would be a Beta distributed RV.  However, since $p\in[0,1]$ it would seem like the prior would only have support in $[0,1]$, but that would mean that any $o_i\in[-1,0]$ would have not lead to any useful information about $p$, which is simply incorrect.

On the other hand, if I have the prior have support over the whole $[-1,1]$ interval and perform the usual Bayesian update, the posterior distribution will indicate $\Pr(p\in[-1,0])\not=0$, which is also incorrect.

What is the appropriate prior and update rule in this case? Has anyone seen problems similar to this one?

Comment: Here's a real-world example: radioactivity measurements of a substance can be negative because the measurement method subtracts a background value and due to noise in the system it's possible for background to exceed the reading.  Nevertheless, the mean of independent repeated measurements ($o_i$) will converge to the true mean ($p$), which must be non-negative.  And *of course* a negative observation causes the updated estimate of $p$ to change, because it must increase the chance of $p$ being small.

Comment: What I had in mind was also a real world example: $o_i$ is the ratio between the expectation value of a particular quantum observable (chosen in a special way) for a quantum state $\hat\sigma$ and the expectation value for the same quantum observable for a theoretical pure state $\hat\rho$, so that $p$ is equal to the fidelity between these two states.

Comment: Just because $p\in [0, 1]$ doesn't mean that observations < 0 will be ignored. Whether or not they will be is determined by $p(o_i | p)$. So (provided that you know or can model $p(o|p)$ well), the Beta prior on $[0, 1]$ seems reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

What if you define $q=\frac{p+1}{2}$ and use a beta prior on $q$?  Then $p$ can be in the $-1$ to $1$ range, but $q$ conforms to the support of the beta distribution.

Comment: The valid ("physical") value for $p$ are within $[0,1]$, and estimating anything other than that is simple incorrect for the problem I am analyzing. More concretely, $p$ is a quantum expectation value of a positive operator, so it can never be negative, _i.e._ $p={\mathrm{tr}}\hat\sigma\hat\rho$ where both $\hat\rho>0$ and $\hat\sigma>0$, and $\hat\rho^2=\hat\rho$.